# Media Import failure in Wordpress (XML import)

Tags: xml, wordpress

I was hosting my website on one hosting platform. Before the hosting got wiped out/deleted, I had exported an XML of the entire content including media(images).

When I try to import the same XML file to my new Wordpress host, all the posts and users get imported but the media fails i.e. I'm not able to retrieve any media.

Any know any solution to get back my media? The old hosting service has been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if the site is gone there is no media to import. The media import only works when the other site exists and the media is accessible. The export file does not contain the media (it's just XML).

Comment: So, this is how a disaster feels like. Thanks.

Comment: Hurts me to write it. Have you got any local backups or anything like that? Might be able to use archive.org to recover some if the site is archived.